# POST Request to Google Analytics with Measurement Protocol from the App Script returns valid response but doesnt work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to send offline conversions data to Google Analytics using the Measurement Protocol

I'm sending this POST Request using the Google AppScripts:

```
function hitPageViewGA (line,sheet) {

  var range = sheet.getRange(line,1,1,10);
  var values = range.getValues();

  var origem = values[0][6];
  var campanha = values[0][7]

  var data =    {'v': '1',
                 'tid': 'UA-81598809-3',
                 'cid': generateUUID_(),
                 'z': Math.floor(Math.random()*10E7),
                 't':'pageview',
                 'dl':'https://77digitalmarketing.com/teste',
                 'cs':origem,
                 'cn':campanha
                };

   var payload = Object.keys(data).map(function(key) {
                                        return encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]);
                                    }).join('&');

  var options = {
  'method' : 'POST',
  'payload' : payload,
  'headers' : {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'}
    }; 


  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https:/www.google-analytics.com//collect',options);

  return response; 
}
```

When I send the request to https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect to validate the request, I get a valid response. Also, when I test the generated payload in the Request Builder , it works! I just doesnt work when the request is done by the Google App Scripts.

Does someone know why that would happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well, turns out it was an IP issue. Google AppsScripts send the requests using some standard IPs that Google Analytics identifies as being bots, so I just needed to specify the IP adress in the request.

Comment: thanks works for me too to specify uip in the request

Comment: Hi there - does this mean you specified the UIP as in this guide? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#using-a-proxy-server

(Basically via parameter in the request url)

Or did you do something else to set the IP? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, it is just a matter of setting the IP in the request parameters

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a typo in the code '//collect'. That might have caused it...

I have been 'banging my head against the wall' whole morning to make Analytics work with Apps Script...

I had a working Apps Script code for another Analytics property. I set up a new property, copied the code and events were not showing up at all. When I sent the same request from Postman I saw it immediately in the real-time dashboard...

To make the story short as I am still quite pissed off and to save you some frustration :) simply disable bot filtering! Go to Admin -> View Settings and disable Bot Filtering option.

For some reason requests coming from Apps Script environment are treated as suspicious...

Comment: I wish I found this answer sooner. I came across the exact same problem.. Thank you.